# "No instance for MonadRandom" when using weightedSample in a monad transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I want to take a weighted sample from a list inside a monad transformer stack.

I've managed to get this minimal example to type-check, but I don't understand the error message I get upon running `main`, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction, FlexibleContexts #-}                                                                                       
module Testing where                                                                                                                               

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO, MonadIO)                                                                                                    
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)                                                                                                            
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy (modify, runStateT, StateT)                                                                                  
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (ask, runReaderT, ReaderT)                                                                                       
import Data.Random                                                                                                                                 
import Data.Random.Distribution.Uniform.Exclusive (Excludable)                                                                                     
import Data.Random.Shuffle.Weighted (weightedSample)                                                                                               

testS :: [(Int, Int)]                                                                                                                              
testS = [(1,c) | c <- [11..20]]                                                                                                                    

loop :: (Num w, Ord w, Show a, MonadIO m, Excludable w, Distribution Uniform w, MonadRandom (StateT [[a]] m)) => ReaderT [(w, a)] (StateT [[a]] m) ()
loop = do
  s <- ask                                                                                                                                         
  a <- lift $ sample $ weightedSample 1 s                                                                                                          
  liftIO $ print a                                                                                                                                 
  lift $ modify ((:) a)                                                                                                                            

main :: (MonadIO m, MonadRandom (StateT [[Int]] m)) => m ((), [[Int]])                                                                             
main = runStateT (runReaderT loop testS) []
```

The actual program is supposed to help with learning by selecting a random question from the initial config (`testS`), and then update the weights in the state so that questions the user got wrong become more likely.

Here is the error I get when running `main` in ghci:

```
 No instance for (random-source-0.3.0.6:Data.Random.Internal.Source.MonadRandom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                   (Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT [[Int]] m0))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  arising from a use of `main'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Possible fix:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  add an instance declaration for                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  (random-source-0.3.0.6:Data.Random.Internal.Source.MonadRandom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     (Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT [[Int]] m0))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
In the expression: main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
In an equation for `it': it = main
```

Comment: Type signature plz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to get `random-fu` installed to test, but based on browsing documentation I still have a guess that might be right.

The line

```
a <- lift $ sample $ weightedSample 1 s
```

Tries to run `sample $ weightedSample 1 s` in the underlying monad

```
StateT [[Int]] IO
```

However, `StateT` monads are only `MonadRandom`s when their state is one of the supported random number generator states.

You probably want to run it in `IO`, which is itself a `MonadRandom`.

In other words, add another `lift`.

BTW if this is right, the reason why it still typechecks initially is that you *could* in theory add an instance for `StateT [[Int]] IO` if you wanted. (But you probably don't.)

Comment: Current maintainer of random-fu here. Can you let me know what the problem is in installing random-fu?

Comment: @DominicSteinitz I delved into it a bit more, and I think I've hit a known bug in Windows GHC, ([my added trac comment here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3242#comment:27)). Basically the install uses the package `logfloat` from Template Haskell, which gets confused about where to find the `m` C library. As a workaround, I reinstalled `logfloat` with `--flags -useFFI`.  After that, the rest installed fine.

Comment: That's annoying but I am happy you managed to get it to work. For info, I added the dependency to minimise the chance of underflow for the log binomial distribution.